# how to create view for django root module

Tags: django, django-views, django-apps

I have a `django project` with nested smaller apps call: `blog`, `research`, `report`.

I would like to create a view at the root folder (django project level) so that it displays all the blog, research and report posts.

what can i do?

usually i wire the django project urls so that the request `''` go to the blog home view. Now i dont want it to be wired that way anymore. I would like that the `''` go to a page (i think at django project root level) that can render all blog, research and report articles.

Comment: Share your project structure and root urls.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just start a new app to handle those 3 types, step by step as usual.